# Rename 'hyphens' tag to 'dash'/'dashes' (or add 'dashes' tag)?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a [hyphens](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphens) tag with 54 questions. Some of these questions are not about hyphens but about other types of dashes, i.e. the [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) and (sometimes) the [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash).

Which of the following should be done to address this?

- Leave the tag [hyphens](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphens) as-is.
- Rename it to [dash](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dash) (or [dashes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dashes), since it would cover several types of dashes) and adapt the tag wiki excerpt to

  > For questions about when and whether to use a certain types of dashes, i.e. the hyphen (-), the en dash, the em dash and the figure dash.
- Add a new tag [dashes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dashes) with the following tag wiki excerpt:

  > For questions about when and whether to use the en dash, the em dash or the figure dash. For questions about hyphens, use the hyphens tag.

If we choose the third option, the tag wiki excerpt for [hyphens](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphens) will need to be edited to add:

> For other types of dashes, use the tag 'dashes'.

Comment: I like the option of creating the new tag, rather than renaming the old one.

Comment: I don't have any sense that dash style is part of language use, whether English or any other.  Of meeting some formal style prescriptions, okay, but not language qua language.  Understanding is never -to *my* best knowledge anyway- dependent on the length of a dash. (Reading wiki's prescriptiveness about the various flavors of dash, I had to laugh.  What on Earth do they do when writing something by hand?  Or is that skill, along with good sense, lost to them?)

Comment: @MMacD It's not just Wikipedia that distinguishes between hyphens and other types of dashes. Check the references in [my answer to an ELL SE question about hyphen & en dash](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/114055/37759).

Comment: Oh, I distinguish between them too, Christophe -- but they're not part of language, they're just stylistic, like capitalisation.  As German still does, 18th-c. writers in English capitalised nouns.  The style changed so that nobody expects nouns to be capitalised in English these days, but the *language* was unchanged.  The ability --and willingness-- to distinguish between dashes is similar:  someone might be sneered at by stylistic pedants for not using the "proper" kind of dash, but few will notice, or care.

Comment: @MMacD Do you think the tag wiki excerpt for [tag:hyphens] should be reworded, then? It currently does not cover other types of dashes.

Comment: I like your third idea best:  2 tags.  To formalise it, I've said so in an answer.

Comment: In [another post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102983#114055), the original poster has stated that concatenated phrases like "well-educated", "en-dash", and words broken over multiple lines like "antidisestab-lishmentarian" use hyphens, whereas numeric ranges like "100-400 meters" use en-dashes.  I do not think that most native speakers of English (whether educated or not) would consider this to be a natural distinction.

Comment: @MMacD Why would dash-style *not* be considered as much a part of the language as any other finer point of punctuation style?

Comment: @KyleStrand:  Because, like capitalisation, they don't affect understanding.  They might affect us on a *social* level, just as knowing or not knowing what fork to use at a formal dinner can affect how we're perceived by those who think such things are important, but the reality is that our ability to communicate is unaffected.  Since which dash we use, or whether we use a dash at all, doesn't alter the meaning of what we're expressing, how can it be part of language rather than styling?  And *typographic* styling at that!

Comment: @MMacD Well, because, presumably, different languages have different rules/guidelines/conventions for their usage. I would say that capitalization differences are *also* part of the language; German capitalization is different from English capitalization. And languages are nothing *but* social convention--every aspect of them, including these "merely" stylistic aspects, *does* impact "our ability to communicate."

Comment: How do you express caps and hyphens in speech?

Comment: @MMacD Do you consider the written word to not be part of a language??

Comment: Yes, I do.  It's a *representation* of the language, but it's not the language.  It's comparable to a map.  Maps aren't the territory, they just represent it.  Plenty people are illiterate in a language they know well, but you'll never find the opposite situation.

Comment: @MMacD You keep responding to me without @-notifying me, so I keep almost missing your responses. (Hence why my last comment took me a few *days* to post.) Anyway, yes, you *will* find the opposite situation; almost no one *speaks* Latin, but many people *read and write* it. Even for non-dead languages, I know people who, for example, find it easy enough to read and write languages that they have great difficulty speaking (for various reasons). And then there are languages such as Japanese with multiple writing systems with their own nuances.

Comment: You could consider written languages to be *separate* languages if you really wanted, but I honestly think it's absurd to say that they're "not languages".

Comment: @KyleStrand:  (Sorry for not @-ing you! I'll try to do better)  We understand written Latin because of its *many* descendants around the Med rim.  If there were no such descendants, we'd be in the same position vis-á-vis Latin as we were with Ancient Egyptian before the Rosetta Stone.  If you'd like a different example, try to decode Linear A, the Vinča texts, the Phaistos disc, or, for a *lot* of fun, the Harappan symbols.  Nobody even knows whether the Harappan symbols represent a language as such, but they look as though a lot of energy went into creating them.

Comment: @MMacD I don't think my previous comment conflicts with your statement about how we know ancient Latin; I'm just saying that many people are literate in Latin but don't know how to *speak* it, which (as I understand it) is indeed the "opposite situation" that you were saying in your comment I'd "never find." I'm not sure what your point is about dead languages no one alive today understands.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I don't know of any evidence that any culture ever developed a *written* form of their language first, but there's lots of evidence of spoken languages that have no standard written representation.  Scots and Low Saxon are two such.  There's a literature in each one, but there's no orthography.  The authors simply represent as best they can their own spoken dialect.

Comment: @KyleStrand:  People who read Latin can also speak it, even if they don't do so in everyday life.  That's true of every language that people can write.  They might have lousy, unintelligible accents because they started learning the language in adulthood, but they can speak it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51467/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-mmacd).

Comment: Sorry but -1 from me because I found only two *questions* tagged hyphen which were actually asking about dashes http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhyphens%5D+dash It doesn't seem to be a significant problem. And one of those dash questions you provided an answer to.

Comment: There are [**44 questions on ELL which mention *dash***](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+dash+) either in the title or in the body, not all are about the actual typographical mark though. The vast majority  are tagged punctuation, which seems fairly accurate. If someone wants to go through each one and retag the questions, they can. Me? I'm stuck with retagging questions which have  *only* the grammar tag.

Answer (score 3):

I like your idea of 2 nominal tags

- hyphens
- dashes

but make them point to the same queue, since learners are likely to know one word but not the other, or think that "hyphen" is a generic term like "dash".

Answer (score 1):

I think we should leave the [hyphens](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyphens) tag as it is.  I just looked through the list of questions.  All 54 questions seem to be about hyphenation.

Comment: What would you think about changing it to hyphenation then?

Comment: As a tag name, "hyphens" has some advantages over "hyphenation".  "Hyphens" is shorter.  I suspect that the singular word "hyphen" is more likely to occur to people than the abstract noun "hyphenation".  I suspect that "hyphens" is more understandable at first glance to a non-native speaker than "hyphenation".

Comment: Fair enough - we could make them synonyms though, so folks could type "hyphen" and the question would end up tagged "hyphenation". It just jumped out to me that you said "all of these questions are about hyphenation" and not "about hyphens".

Comment: as far as I could tell there are only two *questions* currently tagged hyphens which would benefit from a dash tag. http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhyphens%5D+dash